# Why does Lucene DirectoryReader not see any changes made by IndexWriter if opened before any writes?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to create Lucene `IndexWriter` and `DirectoryReader` and keep both open for future use. The trouble - DirectoryReader does not see any changes commited to the index if the DirectoryReader is instantiated before the commits are made.

Please see code below:

```
public class SearchLayer1 {

   private final RAMDirectory directory;
   private final IndexWriter indexWriter;
   private final DirectoryReader directoryReader;

   public SearchLayer1() throws IOException {
      this.directory = new RAMDirectory();
      IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
      this.indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
      this.directoryReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, false);
   }

   public void add() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Document doc = new Document();
      String text = "This is the text to be indexed.";
      doc.add(new StringField("fieldname", text, Field.Store.YES));
      indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
      indexWriter.commit();

      doc = new Document();
      doc.add(new StringField("fieldname", text, Field.Store.YES));
      indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
      indexWriter.commit();
   }


   public void experiment() throws IOException, ParseException {
      //IT WORKS IF THE DirectoryReader IS OPENED AFTER SOME DOCUMENTS ARE ADDED TO THE INDEX 
      //DirectoryReader directoryReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, false);
      IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(directoryReader);
      Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("fieldname", "This is the text to be indexed."));
      ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;

      for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
         Document hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
         System.out.println("==========> " + hitDoc.get("fieldname"));
      }
      directoryReader.close();
   }

   public void close() throws IOException {
      indexWriter.close();

      directory.close();
   }
}
```

And then execute this in unit test:

```
@Test
public void experiment() throws Exception {
   SearchLayer1 searchLayer1 = new SearchLayer1();
   searchLayer1.add();
   searchLayer1.experiment();

   searchLayer1.close();
}
```

I would expect "==========> This is the text to be indexed." to be printed twice, but it does not unless I move the DirectoryReader instantiation down to the `experiment()` method.

So why does DirectoryReader NOT see any commits??
I am using lucene 5.3.1

P.S
Yes I am aware about deprecation of some methods as well as existence of QueryParsers, please do not bother commenting on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this is how Lucene works.
If you open an IndexReader (e.g. via `DirectoryReader.open`), you get a point-in-time view of the index that exists at that particular moment and it won't change until you open the IndexReader again, regardless of indexing activity on the IndexWriter.
But don't just close and open then IndexReader again. What you want to do is to reopen the existing reader. That way, only new segments have be opened and existing segments can be reused instead of always reading the complete index (which is an expensive operation).
A reopen look like this (ommiting code that didn't change):

```
public class SearchLayer1 {
  // ...
  private DirectoryReader directoryReader;
  private IndexSearcher indexSearcher;

  public SearchLayer1() throws IOException {
    // ...
    this.directoryReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, false);
    this.indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(directoryReader);
  }

  // ...

  private void refreshReader() throws IOException {
    DirectoryReader newReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(this.directoryReader);
    if (newReader != null && newReader != this.directoryReader) {
      this.directoryReader.close();
      this.directoryReader = newReader;
      this.indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(this.directoryReader);
    }
  }

  public void experiment() throws IOException {
    refreshReader();
    IndexSearcher isearcher = this.indexSearcher;
    // ...
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    directoryReader.close();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Refreshing right before every search makes sure, that you can always see
the latest changes, but a refresh operation can be quite costly, especially if a merge has happened and large segments have to be opened.
Typically, you'd have a scheduled thread that runs refresh at a certain interval, say, every second.

Also, dealing with the refresh operation itself is fairly low-level.
The code I suggested didn't involve any exception handling in which case
the correct instances of the old reader or the new reader have to be closed
and if you have a dedicated refresh thread, you may not close but `decRef` instead. It is easier and recommended to use a `SearcherManager` instead:

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager;
// ...

public class SearchLayer1 {
  // ...
  private final SearcherManager searcherManager;

  public SearchLayer1() throws IOException {
    // ...
    this.searcherManager = new SearcherManager(indexWriter, false, null);
  }

  // ...

  public void experiment() throws IOException {
    searcherManager.maybeRefresh();
    IndexSearcher isearcher = searcherManager.acquire();
    try {
      // ...
    } finally {
      searcherManager.release(isearcher);
    }
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    searcherManager.close();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Again, better use a separate thread for periodic refreshes.
Either way gives you the output you expected.

Comment: it's fascinating that the existence of SearcherManager isn't even mentioned in any of the usual resources when starting to work with a framework - thanks a lot, that probably saved me much time